# Not redrawing the page when the user presses the Back Button (Using $_GET variables in PHP)

Tags: php, caching, button, dynamic, back

I have a dynamic website with pages drawn using PHP.

Using the $_GET variable I am getting commands from the user, executing PHP based on the $_GET command, and drawing a page.

However, when the user presses the back button I want them to see the page that was dynamically drawn for them before, instead of re-executing code.

I've seen this done, but can't figure out how to do it.

For instance assume the following code:

```
if ($_GET['cmd'] == "time") {
   echo "The current Unix timestamp is: " . time;
}
```

Clicking the url: somepage.php?cmd=time executes the code properly but when using the back button, re-executes the code.  Is there a way using cache, or something else I don't know about, that will allow the user to see the time as it was when the page was drawn, instead of re-executing?

=========================================================================================
To try and be a little more specific, the pages and code that I am talking about perform multiple functions and alter MySQL data based on the commands given then draw the page.

I want to know if there is a way, when using the back button, to not re-execute but to just show the page that was drawn dynamically the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it may be of help. Rather than using php get, you might use ajax and then implement this: http://www.nerdswithlives.com/2010/03/yui-ajax-browser-history-back-button.html

You could also have some type of variable stored every time a specific get command is executed, then check for that variable to determine which content to redraw on page load.

**EDIT**

From thinking more about your problem, I believe the answer lies with using PHP Sessions, and storing data on the clients machine. When a user clicks "back" he/she IS going to the cached page... so caching is not your answer. You need it re-drawn a specific way, but because you are using GET, the browser does NOT cache this... at least with back button functionality anyway. Your answer is to start a session on each page this dynamic content exists, store a variable like `$_SESSION['sessionVar'] = 1;` or whatever. Then dynamically change the variable depending on what was drawn on that page. Then, when the user clicks "back" you can check for whatever that variable is and get the data again. Get out of the mindset of using cache for this - you need to RE-DRAW whatever data the user saw previously. Sessions would be useful in this case.

Comment: This is not quite what I'm looking for but thank you for the quick response.

Comment: No problem. Maybe showing more of your code (an example of the dynamic content being drawn...) could help us understand what your attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at using `$_SESSION`

```
if ($_GET['cmd'] == "time") {
   $_SESSION['time'] = isset($_SESSION['time']) ? $_SESSION['time'] : time;
   echo "The current Unix timestamp is: " . $_SESSION['time'];
}
```

Comment: That code was just an example of what I meant, however the actual code over several different files performs several actions including interacting with MySQL databases to draw output.  I just want to show the page at the state that it was drawn at that time, if that is possible.

Comment: could take a look at APC then, or memcache

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTTP caching headers. There are three strategies:

- Expire times
- ETags
- Last Modification times

The first one sets a date/time for the page to expire. This can be achieved sending a header:

```
header('Expires: Thu, 28 Apr 2012 16:00:00 GMT');
```

The main problem with this approach is that you cannot invalidate this cache. This means that if you *want* to redraw everything to update something on the page, you'll have to wait for the cache to expire.

ETags have better control, but are harder to implement:

```
$etag = md5($pageId);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) 
    && false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'], $etag)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    die;
} else {
    header('ETag: '.$etag);
    //draw the page
}
```

When a browser hits the page for the first time, the page is drawn and an `ETag` header is served. Next time the browser hits the page, it will send an HTTP request header `If-None-Match` with the previous ETag value. The server must compare this header with the current ETag, if they're the same, the server only needs to send an empty body and a `304 Not Modified` status. The ETag can be anything that identifies the page content and version in an unique way.

Last Modification works similar to ETags, but instead of server-generated tags, it uses dates. Date comparison must be done considering later and previous dates as well.

[Section 13 of the HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) covers all these mechanisms and its gotchas. It's a hard reading, but it is worth.

Comment: This looks more like what I need.  I will try this and certainly look into ETag.  Thank you alganet for your time!

Comment: This does not appear to be solving the back button issue.

Comment: Try interacting with the page having Firebug on and following requests on the Net tab. You should see how requests are cached. Also, there are headers that influence the caching mechanism, Cookies, for instance.